# How to change TextFormField() widget color Flutter

Tags: forms, flutter, colors, program-entry-point, textformfield

I changed primary color black to white.
my all TextFormField() focus color became white.
how can I change this Color
I tryed to change color properties but doens't work at all

```
 TextFormField(
     style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
     focusNode: _confirmPasswordFocusNode,
     obscureText: true,
     decoration: InputDecoration(
     fillColor: Colors.black54,
     hoverColor: Colors.black54,
     focusColor: Colors.black54,
     labelText: '비밀번호 확인',
     icon: Icon(Icons.lock_outline)),
     onChanged: (value) {
        ...
```

[image]

everybody somebody anybody help me
body : TextFormField(),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't change because of the default scheme set to the screen.

You just have to change the widgets that you are drawing by wrapping your TextFormField with new ThemeData()

```
      Theme(
          data: new ThemeData(
            primaryColor: Colors.black54,
            focusColor: Colors.black54,
            hintColor: Colors.black54,
          ),
          child: TextFormField(
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
            obscureText: true,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: '비밀번호 확인', icon: Icon(Icons.lock_outline)),
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

put cursorColor: Colors.white, inside TextFormField

```dart
TextField(
  cursorColor: Colors.red,
),
```

or

set the cursorColor for theme attribute when calling MaterialApp like

```dart
    MaterialApp(
        title: "Flutter App",
        theme: ThemeData(
        cursorColor: Colors.red,
        home: HomeScreen(),)
```

Comment: but.. I meant not cursor , entire icon and underline 